# Nonlinear ODE of second order.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have problems finding out whether this initial value problem has an explicit form solution or if it is possible to grind out a term-by-term representation of this solution using power series expansions.

\begin{equation}
f^{\prime\prime}(x)-\frac{f(x)-a}{b}f^{\prime}(x)=0,\qquad f(1/2)=a,\, f^{\prime}(1/2)=\sqrt{2\pi b}, \qquad x\in(0,1).
\end{equation}
where $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $b\in(0,\infty)$ are constants.

I have tried the considering the following: Rewrite the $f^{\prime}$ term in order to obtain an equation of first order. But I get stuck in the substitutions as I do not know what to make of the $f$ term.

Any help or hint is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, $g(x):=f(x)-a$ gives us a simplification $$g''=g'g/b,\quad g(1/2) =0,\quad g'(1/2)=\sqrt {2\pi b}.$$
Next, change of variables $y=2x-1$, so the interval becomes $(-1,1)$, initial data is taken at zero.

$$h(y):=g((y+1)/2),\quad 4h''(y) = g'' ((y+1)/2),\quad \quad 2h'(y) = g' ((y+1)/2).$$
The equation becomes
$$h''(y)= \frac{h(y)h'(y)}{2b},\quad h(0) =0,\quad h'(0)=\frac{\sqrt {2\pi b}}{2}. $$

We can integrate this equation:
$$h'(y) = \frac{h^2}{4b}+C,\quad h(0) =0,\quad h'(0)=\frac{\sqrt {2\pi b}}{2}.$$
We find $C$ from initial conditions: $C= h'(0)=\frac{\sqrt {2\pi b}}{2}>0$.
At last, we obtain something of the first order. Once we recall that $\tan x'= \tan^2 x+1$, the further direction of reasoning is clear. We make another scaling of variables; if
$$h(y) = A\tan(By),$$then$$   h' (y) =   AB(\tan^2(By)+1)=  \frac BA h^2(y) +AB= \frac{h^2}{4b}+ \frac{\sqrt {2\pi b}}{2}.$$

All we have to do now is to solve $$\frac BA =\frac{1}{4b},$$
$$ AB=   \frac{\sqrt {2\pi b}}{2},$$
plug $A$, $B$ back to $h$ and  revert all our changes of variables and translations back to $f$.

Answer (score 0):

If we think of $f$ as the independent variable (this step might take some justification), we can write $f'(x)=g(f)$. Then, by the chain rule, $f''(x) =\frac{dg}{dx} = \frac{dg}{df}\frac{df}{dx}$

Using this substitution, we can rewrite the DE as

$$
\frac{dg}{df}f'(x)-\frac{f-a}{b}f'(x)=0\\
\frac{dg}{df}=\frac{f-a}{b}
$$

This is a separable DE, which we can solve by integration. This gives us a solution for $g$. We can then use this to perform a substitution which will reduce the order of the original DE by 1. The resulting equation will also be separable, and can be solved by integration to find the general solution.

Comment: I am not sure how to process this information. By the chain rule, $(f^{\prime}\circ f)^{\prime}=(f^{\prime\prime}\circ f)\cdot f^{\prime}$. How is this equal to $f^{\prime\prime}$ and furthermore, how does this help me reduce the equation?

Comment: I am not even sure that the expression $f^\prime\circ f$ makes sense for all $x\in(0,1)$, since $f$ may take values outside the domain of $f^\prime$.

Comment: I meant $f'' = \frac{df'}{dx} = \frac{df'}{df}\frac{df}{dx}$. I'll elaborate a bit more in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

substitute values  of $f(\frac{1}{2})$ &$f'(\frac{1}{2})$ on the above equation  and you get $f''(\frac{1}{2}) = 0$.approximating using Taylor expansion for $f(x)$ centered at $x = \frac{1}{2}$ is,
$$f(x) = \frac{f(  \frac{1}{2} )}{0!} + \frac{f'(  \frac{1}{2} )}{1!}x + \frac{f''(  \frac{1}{2} )}{2!}x^2 $$
or $$f(x)_{x = \frac{1}{2}} \approx a + x\sqrt{2πb}$$

Answer (score 0):

The solution by TZakrevskiy is nice. I will add that after the same change of variables, he suggests, to obtain:
$$ g'' = \frac{g}{2b} g'$$
with boundary conditions of:
$$ g(0)=0$$ and
$$ g'(0)=\frac{\sqrt{2 \pi b}}{2} $$
you can apply the general solution of that nonlinear ODE as given in the handbook by Polyanin and Zaitsev:

For a general equation of the form $g''=f(g)g'$ and $g=g(x)$ the solution is:

$$ \int \frac{dg}{F(g) + C_1}=C_2 + x $$

where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are the integration constants and $F(g)=\int f(g) dg$. Applying this will yield the same $tan$ based solution as noted above.

Cheers,

Paul Safier